# Java regex for string pattern

Tags: java, regex

I would want to write a regex for this string pattern:

```
<Col name="SKU_UPC_NBR">85634546495</Col>
```

I want to fetch the value between Col tag.

I tried the below pattern :

```
Pattern TAG_REGEX = Pattern.compile("<Col name='SKU_UPC_NBR'>(.+?)</col>");
Matcher matcher = TAG_REGEX.matcher(str);
```

The above is not matching my string and returns empty.
Please help me on this problem.

Comment: You have double quotation marks for the name value in your string but single quotation marks in your pattern. Also, the ending tag in your string is `</Col>` but your pattern is `</col>`.

Comment: Pattern TAG_REGEX = Pattern.compile("<Col name='SKU_UPC_NBR'>(.+?)</Col>");      I modified like this but still not working. I am passing SKU_UPC_NBR in single quotes because I am already setting double quotes for <Col name.

Comment: @NarayananChandramohan Take a look at my answer and try it, if you need more modifications let me know.

Comment: Read about java escape sequences... This is very basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex matches **exactly** what you type.  It does not generalize, it does not understand that sometimes to you `' == "`, it does not match mixing cases.

The data format you've specified is *open tag, space, name attribute, equals, **double quote**, name attr data ...*
The regex format you've specified is *open tag, space, name attribute, equals, **single quote**, name attr data ...*

What you need is

```
Pattern TAG_REGEX = Pattern.compile("<Col name=\"SKU_UPC_NBR\">(.+?)</Col>");
```

**NOTE:** You may want to use `(\d+?)` instead of `(.+?)` as `\d` will match any digit, so the regex is more specific to the data you're matching, and is easier to read.  This won't work however, if you know some `Col` tags won't have just digits in them

---

You may want to refer to [this neat interactive Regex tutorial](https://regexone.com/) for practice with regex's.

You also may want to refer to the [Java documentation for Regex patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), this is useful when you need special characters.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
<Col[^>]*>(.+?)<\/Col>
```

1. `<Col[^>]*>` will match the opening tag. `[^>]*` means match any character but >, so that the match ends at the first > encountered.
2. `(.+?)` means grab 1 or more characters between the opening and closing tag
3. `<\/Col>` this matches the closing tag

Comment: It's always a good idea to explain how your solution works.  Just giving code without explanation doesn't help the OP know how or why it works m, nor what the original issue was

Answer (score 1):

Try this please:

```
(?<=">)\d*(?=<\/)
```

It will match 0 or more digits preceded by "> (quotation mark and greater than sign) and followed by (less than sign and forward slash)

You can test this here:

https://regex101.com/